# How to `open` and `close` a serial port asynchronously?

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, serial-port, aio

I'm trying to use serial ports in an async manner. I can use `select`, `poll`, or `epoll` with `O_NONBLOCK` to do async read and writes. But what about `open` and `close`?

I've seen `close` block for more than a second.

Comment: Why do you want to use polling API (`select`, `poll` etc) with non blocking fds ? They return whenever a following write/read shall not block and with nonblocking fds this is always even though there is nothing to read.

Comment: Because I don't want 100 percent cpu and I have more than one fd.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that `select` for instance doesn't wait for an fd to be readable, it waits for the moment when a subsequent read will not block, which is always for `O_NONBLOCK` file descriptors.

Comment: There is a non-blocking option for open(), but there are no options for close().  Besides, you shouldn't be making these syscalls that often, so why would it even matter?  *"I don't want 100 percent cpu"* -- Seems like you don't understand the purpose of blocking I/O in a multiprocessing environment.  *"I have more than one fd."* -- That may be the most sensible thing you wrote, but you bury it in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very few operating systems which implement true asynchronous `open()` and `close()` (specifying `O_NONBLOCK` to `open()` means don't sleep waiting for connection or input, not actually perform the operation truly in the background). Two that come to mind are QNX and the Hurd, both are micro-kernel operating system designs where every syscall is by definition multiplexable and therefore asynchronous.

As to why, historically you can't do anything until an `open()` completes so API designers never thought to make it async. More recently, if you really want it to be async, do the call from a threadpool. `close()` is a bit more interesting, it's actually pretty hard to make closing a file descriptor fast without making it lose valuable information the loss of which will cause data loss e.g. "the buffered data I just tried to write out failed". But again, if you really need `close()` to be async, just call it from a threadpool.

As a general rule, you cannot expect high performance if you call `open()` and `close()` a lot. Both inevitably involve making the kernel run a lot of code checking perms, allocating kernel structures, taking locks on kernel structures etc. Generally for high performance file i/o for example, you open the files you need at the beginning and never close them. That gets good to superb performance on most operating systems.